# Tableselect with columns of checkboxes

Tags: forms

I've a simple tableselect with 4 columns, in the 3 last columns a want to populate all the columns with checkboxes, anyone can help me to do that ?

here is my actual code :

```
function liste_sections($form, &$form_state){
$form = array();

$header = array(
        'sections' => t('Sections'),
        'affichable'=>t('Affichable'),
        'new'=>t('New'),
        'online'=>t('Online'),
);

$resultat = db_select('taxonomy_term_data','tax');
$resultat->fields('tax',array('tid','name'));
$res = $resultat->execute(); 

$rows = array();
    foreach($res as $sql){
        $rows [] = array(
            'sections' => $sql-> name,
          // Time to put checkboxes for other columns
            );
    }

$form['liste_sec'] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $rows,
        '#empty' => t('empty ! '),
);

$form['ok'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('submit'),
    );
return $form;
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I got it, in my liste_sections($form, &$form_states)

```
$checkbox_col1 = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    );

$checkbox_col2 = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    );

$checkbox_col3 = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    );
```

after that, add those variables to the rows :

```
$rows = array();
    foreach($res as $sql){
        $rows [] = array(
            'sections' => $sql-> name,
            'affichable' => array('data'=>$checkbox_col1),
            'News' => array('data'=>$checkbox_col2),
            'online' => array('data'=>$checkbox_col3),
            );
    }
```